# synchronize mysql server to local db: csv or sqlite?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

### I'm looking for the most efficient way to regularly update my MySQL server with data stored across several local .csv files.

I have a local database of scraped and parsed data from the web.  I process it in python, and the final step is a human audit of a csv file with the help of excel vba scripts.

For updating the server based on this audited data, is it worthwhile to first use python to load my csv data into an sqlite database, or should I be feeding the csv's directly to my server?  What are my options for automating this synchronization?  The MySQL database serves as a master to several client databases, but will only be fed updates from a single (my local) machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Just update the MySQL database directly, why would you write the data to a sqlite database and then write the same data to a MySQL database, unless there's something I'm missing..?

Comment: I imagine there may be existing methods of setting up a mysql database as a slave to a local sqlite db that would not be available for the csv option.  I would think that with the csv option you'd need to upload the entire file to the server with each update, then create a table, then compare it with the existing database.  Ideally I would have architecture that supports comparing the local db to the server db and only making changes where needed.

Comment: "You imagine there may be" as in you know for sure that what you want doesn't exist, or just guessing? I can't help (or at least try to!) if I don't really know what the problem is. My answer so far is: load csv into python, update/insert/whatever MySQL database in question. You can have python code to compare the differences, or sql code, or ruby code, or whatever, I don't see a reason why an sqlite middle man would be needed :/

Comment: Apologies if I'm not being clear.  Embedded in my question is 'Are there advantages in synching mysql with sqlite vs csv?'  Sounds like you aren't aware of any.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the problem is @Matthew not being aware, it's just something really odd to do and if any, it's probably something ad-hoc you won't be able to reuse. If you were talking about multiple MySQL servers, that's a different scenario.